# Querying with mongoengine and django

Tags: django, mongoengine

I have a database "tumblelog" (using mongoengine) in which I added some data in the "user" collection with a "User" model:

> db.user.find()

```
...
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fb0c9494ca88402dd000000"), "_types" : [ "User" ], "first_name" : "John", "last_name" : "Doe", "_cls" : "User", "email" : "jdoe@example.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fb0cb9d4ca88402ec000000"), "_types" : [ "User" ], "first_name" : "Joe30", "last_name" : "Foe", "_cls" : "User", "email" : "hu@huu.com" }
```

When I try `User.objects` in a django shell, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../mongoengine/queryset.py", line 1127, in __getitem__
     return self._document._from_son(self._cursor[key])
  File ".../mongoengine/base.py", line 1018, in _from_son
     obj = cls(**data)
  TypeError: __init__() keywords must be strings
```

Same thing when I try

```
for user in User.objects:
    print user.first_name
```

---- Edit ----

I tried this

```
>>> users = User.objects
>>> users.count()
7
>>> users.first()
...
TypeError: __init__() keywords must be strings
```

---- Edit 2 ----

I installed my project this way :

```
> virtualenv Test
> source Test/bin/activate
> pip install Django
> pip install mongoengine
> cd Test/
> django-admin.py startproject db
```

Then I added the lines

```
from mongoengine import *
connect('tumblelog')
```

in settings.py 
then I created this simple model

```
from mongoengine import *

class User(Document):
email = StringField(required=True)
name = StringField(max_length=50)
```

then I run the server

```
> python manage.py runserver
```

And in the shell (python manage.py shell) I can save data if I import my model class but I can't read it, I always have the same TypeError: **init**() keywords must be strings !

-----Switching to django-mongodb engine----

I didn't find any solution so I will use django-mongodb-engine. I did not find any comparison, but I tried both and it's very similar. 
I just regret django-mongodb-engine doesn't handle inheritance principle.

What am I doing wrong ? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it erroring on the loop or the print line?

Comment: Can you provide example data?  what is in the `data` dict?

Comment: I have the error in this simple project (with virtualenv, no sql and a fresh install of the last django and mongoengine) : mediafire.com/?9d00eitagggueui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we had the exact same issue using mongoengine 0.6.9.  I am not suggesting this as an ideal solution but downgrading to 0.6.5 resolved this issue for us.

Comment: I'd love a test case / some example data as I can't replicate this.

Comment: I have the error in this simple project : http://www.mediafire.com/?1iejsf3g3pyzc11

Comment: A better example (with virtualenv, no sql and a fresh install of the last django and mongoengine) : http://www.mediafire.com/?9d00eitagggueui

Comment: Have you ever given a thought to trying a [Django MongoDB connector](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/) instead? What it does is it connects the original Django ORM to MongoDB, Which means you get all the features of Django ORM

Answer (score 0):

use the all() method

```
for user in User.objects.all():
    print user.first_name
```

Comment: User.objects.all() works.. tell me the error it shows if you use objects.all()

Comment: and also users.first()?? you wanted to derive first_name of all the users, isn't it?. users.objects is a default model manager which doesn't have a method first(). So obviously users.first() won't work.
try .all() and tell me what error it shows. you must be making some silly mistake.

Comment: you can refer this for making queries. and check the syntax https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/

Comment: I am using mongoengine (or I try to) 

http://readthedocs.org/docs/mongoengine-odm/en/latest/apireference.html#querying

There is a first() function:
Retrieve the first object matching the query.

The problem is I always get the "TypeError: __init__() keywords must be strings" wherever I try User.objects or User.objects.all()